# Проблемы с портами usb-c ноутбука

Tags: ноутбук, разъёмы

Я после ночной посиделки за ноутбуком, утром обнаружил что 2 моих порта usb-c не работают. Я пробовал подключать внешний ssd диск, внешний монитор ничего не работает.  Я пробовал заряжать ноут через эти разъёмы но тоже безуспешно. У меня ноут Asus TUF GAMING A15 2023, с момента покупки только 2 месяца.

Я зашёл в диспетчер устройств и увидел это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста помогите мне с моей ситуацией.

Comment: но всё было хорошо часов 10 назад

Comment: раз уж видно в диспетчере проблемное устройство - стоило в него зайти и уже там сделать скриншот ошибки, или скопировать её текст например сюда в вопрос(там достаточно читабельный текст, иногда по нему и без спец навыков ясно что надо делать). а вообще, если 2 месяца с **официальной покупки**, можно просто оттащить в сервис по гарантии. да и написать в официальный саппорт тоже никто не запрещает.

Comment: Учитывая также, что у вас еще есть «другие устройства», то можно смело предположить, что с драйверами у вас непорядок вообще.

Answer (score 0):

На обведённом в контекстном меню есть команда обновить драйвер. Попробуй. Если не получится, то скачай с сайта ASUS для этой модели драйвер чипсета и установи.